# ¿Cómo consultar los datos a partir de los nombres de dos personas?

Tags: sql

Estoy aprendiendo SQL server y no sé como obtener los datos de dos personas a partir del query de abajo, en la expresión:

```
 Liders.Nombre = ('Yoni Albino''Luis Benítez')
```

Si le quito uno de los nombres ejecuta la consulta correctamente, pero quisiera traer los datos de ambas personas.

```
select distinct 
Participantes.nombre,Participantes.apellido,Participantes.Cedula,
Preguntas.Descripcion,Respuestas.Contenido,cursoes.nombre 
curso,Participantes.LugarDeTrabajo,CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Finalizo,
Liders.Nombre, Liders.Apellido
from respuestas, CursoPlaneadoParticipantes, CursoPlaneadoes, 
Participantes,Cursoes, Preguntas, Liders
where Cursoes.Nombre = 'Finanzas Personales Proceso' 
and FechaInicio BETWEEN '20180201 00:00:00' And '20180623 23:59:59' and 
Liders.Nombre = ('Yoni Albino''Luis Benítez') 
and respuestas.preguntaid = 196 AND Preguntas.Descripcion = 'Se expresa en 
forma clara y sencilla'
and CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Id = respuestas.CursoPlaneadoParticipanteId
and CursoPlaneadoes.Id = CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.CursoPlaneadoId
and Participantes.Id = CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.ParticipanteId
and Cursoes.Id = CursoPlaneadoes.CursoId
and CursoPlaneadoes.LiderId = Liders.Id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utiliza el operador `IN` en vez del el operador `=`

```
Liders.Nombre IN ('Yoni Albino','Luis Benítez')
```

Nota que los nombres van separados por coma.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta como podría hacer si quiero extraer los datos de más de dos personas? es con la misma sentencia IN? supongamos que son 3 personas

Comment: Solo lo separas por otra coma y colocas en comillas simples el valor `Liders.Nombre IN ('Yoni Albino','Luis Benítez','Albert Hidalgo','Fulano','Jose Perez')`

Comment: Funciona mil gracias!

Comment: @user3802081 si esta respuesta te ha solucionado el problema, considera marcarla como válida dando clic en check verde `✓` que está al lado izquierdo de esta respuesta